# HTTP nginx to HTTPS proxy_pass returns 504 BAD Gateway

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to creating a proxy_pass to a https address (my nginx is running under 80 using plain HTTP protocol).

This is my declaration in conf file:

```
   location /viacep/ {
                  proxy_pass https://viacep.com.br/;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header Host $host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
```

Well, the idea is when I enter in `localhost/viacep/ws/09340400/json` I got the following address resolution under the hood: https://viacep.com.br/ws/09340400/json. But I got the following error in error.log file:

```
2021/12/28 09:32:59 [error] 34664#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /viacep/ws/09540400/json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://165.227.126.241:443/ws/09540400/json", host: "localhost"
```

I imagine this error occurs because of the address resolved (https://165.227.126.241:443/ws/09540400/json), look it using IP instead of DNS.

**Edit 1**

I tried add `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` but same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NGINX will allways resolve the DNS Name to an IP address.

The problem could be with the backend-servers SNI. Given there are multiple sites hosted on this server and the server supports SNI you should send the `server name` by using `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` in your NGINX configuration.

I have just configured that on my NGINX Version `1.20`

```sh
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://viacep.com.br/;
    proxy_set_header Host viacep.com.br;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  }
}
```

Make sure you are sending the right `Host` header. In your configuration you are sending `localhost` as `Host` to the upstream server. This will not work as you have noticed correctly.

Comment: I tried but same error. I added 'proxy_ssl_server_name on'.

Comment: I have just created as small PoC on my server. See the updated config.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was Host header, I was using $Host as you noted, changing to viacep.com.br solved the problem. very thanks